# create procedure dynamic in HANA XS

Tags: hana, hana-xs

I am trying to "translate" the following command into dynamic SQL to be used in a procedure:

```
SELECT *, 'IDS' AS SYSID FROM MODE_TEST.USR02
```

Can someone help with this question? I am facing problems with the 'IDS'.

thanks,

regards,

Comment: Please, clarify, what is dynamic in this code and what the *problems* do you have? If this is some errors, then please post them here as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below:

```
do begin
declare str nvarchar(1000);
str='SELECT *,''IDS'' AS "SIYSID" FROM MODE_TEST.USR02';
execute immediate :str;
end;
```

Comment: It has no difference compared to plain select. So what is the reason to complicate simple and straightforward way to do simple tasks?

Comment: The question was to embed the select stmt as dynamic SQL within procedure, and pass a value ( which is IDS) in a column within single quotes, hence the answer.

Comment: Dynamic call just to make it dynamic makes no sense. This way instead of plain `select` statement you may also join to `dummy` table or do any other identity transformation, but what is the purpose?

Comment: In HANA DB, in order to capture results from select , we need to execute it using 'execute immediately' clause, questioner must have had the requirement.